# Getting html tables to lay cells horizontally

Tags: html

I have html tables inside a huge table that I'm trying to get to to lay their cells horizontally dynamically generated by php. Right now my structure looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            1
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            2
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and the html my chrome browser is rendering outputs the cells like this:

1
2

instead of:

1 2

I know I can just as easily do this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and have my desired output of:

1 2

but I have some info that won't fit clean in a td cell in a table. Any help?

Comment: Don't use nested tables.

Comment: @bjb568 Why? Any suggestions?

Comment: Because tables are for tabular data - you probably don't need tables at all.

Comment: Nah, I need my data to fit into a grid for presentation purposes. Think photo grid of 5x5 all generated dynamically by php.

Comment: That isn't tabular data. Grids are for CSS.

Comment: I don't see why something will not fit cleanly in a td cell. Could you explain more on this please?

Comment: @IzaazYunus Sure. <a href="post.php?id=' . $post_id . '"><img src="uploads/thumb_' . $photo . '" width="150" height="150"><span class="grey">' . $i . '. Posted By <a href="post.php?id=' . $member_id . '">' . $member_name . '</a> on ' . $post_nice . '</a></span><form action="post.php" method="post" id="vote_form">
      <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>" id="post_id">
      <input type="submit" name="post_upvote" value="+" id="post_upvote" onclick="javascript:post_vote('u')"><input type="submit" name="post_downvote" value="-" id="post_dow........

Comment: If you need a 5x5 table, what's wrong with 5 '<tr>'s, each with 5 '<td>'s in? Nested tables is never a good idea, why won't the data fit into table cells?

Comment: Why not use a bunch of inline-block elements in block containers?

Comment: @user3423909 Could you wrap each of these in a div and 'inline-block' them (or float left). The width of the container will determine how many are arranged horizontally, so make their outer container wide enough to only contain 5 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use "float: left" and put some text after the table, it positions next to the table, not in the bottom.
Use

```
td table {
   float: left;
   /*or:
   display: inline-block;*/
}
```

Comment: floats them side by side, but not in a 5x5 grid that I wanted. This can be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Use float:left for table CSS

```
table{
    float:left;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6tp2E/1/)

Comment: need to create a grid of 5x5 table cells. I dno't think Css can help me with that.